# VBA - Runtime Error 424 - Object Required

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Trying to click a Hyperlink on a IE browser by using Getelementsbytagname & referencing the inner text but receiving a

> 424 error

on the `If Link1.InnerText =` line

```
Sub OpenIE()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'Make Explorer visible
objIE.Visible = True

'Open browser
objIE.navigate "https://allabout-japan.com/en/article/287/"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim LINK1 As Object

For Each LINK1 In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If LINKl.innerText = "Tokyo Dining" Then
        LINKl.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next LINK1
```

Comment: `LINK1` <> `LINKl`  If you use `Option Explicit` you would see this right away.

Comment: @TimWilliams beat me by like 5 seconds

Comment: Awesome - thanks Tim